# Add tags to iam amazon web services

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm using cloudformation to create one admins group for my aws account, and I need to add a custom tag to all of them in order to save their e-mail for notification purpouse. There's no info in [aws docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-user.html#aws-properties-iam-user-prop) about it.

Is possible tag an IAM resource? I know that is possible to do it for a [EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently **no IAM objects** can be tagged, in cloudfront or using administration console.

I suppose that since Tags are mostly used for billing and resource grouping, and IAM objects are free of charge and represent authority, roles and permissions and not a resource or a general purpose database.

I think the best alternative for your scenario would be something like DynamoDB to store this configuration.